# httpPost setEntity always empty

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a post to a node.js server but for some reason the body is always empty for me no matter what I try. 
I'm testing now towards requestb.in and its always empty there too.

This is the code I use for posting:

```
public static String post(String url, String json) {
    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://requestb.in/14a9s7m1");
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{'string':'string'}", HTTP.UTF_8);
        se.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("hmac", Methods.getMethods().getHmac(json));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (readLine != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(readLine);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
            readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

This is the requestb.in http://requestb.in/14a9s7m1?inspect 
raw body should contain the json string, right?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make many mistakes when using `HttpUrlConnection`. I admit that I don't see any error, but this doesn't mean anything.

Since Google doesn't recommend using HttpClient and AndroidHttpClient (except for FROYO or older), but [we should use HttpUrlConnection](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) instead, you're on the right way (from a Android perspective).

When using a very lightweight wrapper for HttpUrlConnection called [DavidWebb](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb), the code looks like this (I left out hmac-generation):

```
public class TestWebbRequestBin {

    @Test public void stackOverflow20543115() throws Exception {
        Webb webb = Webb.create();
        webb.setBaseUri("http://requestb.in");

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("string", "string");
        String json = jsonObject.toString(); // {"string":"string"}

        Response<String> response = webb
                .post("/1g7afwn1")
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-type", "application/json")
                .header("hmac", "some-hmac-just-a-test")
                .body(json)
                .asString();

        assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());
        assertTrue(response.isSuccess());

        String body = response.getBody();
        assertEquals("ok\n", body);
    }

}
```

When the JSON I post looks like in your example, `requestb.in` does accept it:

```
    json = "{'string':'string'}";
```

But this is not valid JSON (here tested in node.js):

```
> JSON.parse("{'string':'string'}")
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
    at Object.parse (native)
    at repl:1:7
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
```

**tl;dr**

- Take care to send valid JSON
- Master `HttpUrlConnection` or use a simple abstraction library

For nasty bugs you could either debug your node.js code (or `console.log(req)`) or use a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Is it possible to post a file and text using your library? If so is there an example anywhere or something else that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, the library has no implementation for multi-part. So if you want to upload a file and form values in **one** request, this is not supported. Of course you can post the content of a file or text. If you have a GitHub account, please create an issue at the project. I'll help you with examples as soon as I exactly know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to send the string.... In HttpPost you should use key value pairs to send the data.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("REQUEST", req));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get HttpPost to work, but HttpUrlConnection works instead. It solves my problem, but doesn't solve the mysterious no body thing of httpPost.

Here is my solution:

```
public static String post(String ur2l, String json) {
    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(ur2l);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("hmac", Methods.getMethods().getHmac(json));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(json.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        os.close();

        conn.connect();
        int respCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (respCode == 200) {
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (readLine != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(readLine);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
                readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure is this the problems. Can you give a tried?

You are sending invalid JSON format string. This make server unable to accept your invalid json string so your body is empty. To solve this, change following code.

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{\"string\":\"string\"}", HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Comment: You are correct - this is correct JSON and should solve some problems in real world. `requestb.in` seems to ignore this and consume any payload without complaining.